# Constantly moving an object using translateX inside the parent, what's wrong with my calculation?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using [Anime.js](https://animejs.com/) (but I think it's not relevant) which constantly call my function `computeMinMaxTranslateX` for moving **target** inside the **parent**, without overflowing.

My assumption is that:

- The `translateX` **minimum** value is given by target x offset minus container x offset
- The `translateX` **maximum** value is given by container width minus element width minus element x offset (bacause the previous position should be taken into account)

Is there something wrong with my reasoning? It's not working, the target is overflowing the container. Here is the function i wrote:

```
const computeMinMaxTranslateX = (element, container) => {
  const {
    x: elementX,
    width: elementWidth,
  } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const {
    x: containerX,
    width: containerWidth,
  } = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    min: -(elementX - containerX),
    max: containerWidth - (elementX - containerX) - elementWidth
  };
};
```

[image: Explanation of the problem]
[image: Example]

Comment: Maybe `translateX` don't add to, but replaces `elementX`, so you dont need to take that in account. Simply  `min: containerX, max: containerWidth + containerX - elementWidth`